# Norconex HTTP Collector Tagger Fields

Tags: web-crawler, amazon-cloudsearch

I am using Norconex HTTP Collector and Importer. Where do I find information on the fields that are available for the tagger. I.E. the fields that would go here:

```
<tagger class="com.norconex.importer.handler.tagger.impl.KeepOnlyTagger">
     <fields>id,title,keywords,description,content,document.reference, document.contentType</fields>
</tagger>
```

I'm specifically looking for the status code of the webpage (200, 404, etc...) and the origin of the url (So, if the url was http://www.example.com/page/welcome I'd want http://www.example.com)

I can't find any information online and I've been searching for hours

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer comes pretty late, but our community support site for HTTP Collector is [here](https://github.com/Norconex/collector-http/issues).

The `KeepOnlyTagger` is part of the Importer module and you can find documentation for it on its site: https://www.norconex.com/collectors/importer/configuration#tbl-tagger

Have a look at [this Github ticket](https://github.com/Norconex/collector-http/issues/514) open that covers capturing the site domain. It discusses a few ways. One is to use a `ReplaceTagger` like this:

```
...
<importer>
    ...
    <preParseHandlers>
        ...
        <tagger class="com.norconex.importer.handler.tagger.impl.ReplaceTagger">
            <replace fromField="document.reference" toField="MyCustomDomainField"
                        regex="true" wholeMatch="true">
                <fromValue>https?://(.*?)(/.*|:.*|$)</fromValue>
                <toValue>$1</toValue>
            </replace>
        </tagger>
        ...
    </preParseHandlers>
    ...
</importer>
...
```

Invalid URLs are not sent to your `Committer`, but you can capture all HTTP status codes with an event listener. You can use the [URLStatusCrawlerEventListener](https://www.norconex.com/collectors/collector-http/latest/apidocs/com/norconex/collector/http/crawler/event/impl/URLStatusCrawlerEventListener.html) which does just that.